# Display a total of a collection

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

In Lightswitch 2013 I want to show the total number of items (Incidents) in a given query (FilteredIncidents) on the screen - something like:

> "Showing 200 of 5000 Incidents".

However, I'm only able to get the number of items that are loaded on the screen. How can I show the total?

This is what I'm doing to get the count of the items that have been loaded on the screen:

```
myapp.BrowseIncidents.TotalIncidents_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind('screen.FilteredIncidents.count', function (value) {
        contentItem.screen.TotalIncidents = value;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a function like this. You can adjust the parameters to suit, like pass in an element rather than and id:

```
    function getTotalCount(entitySet, elemId) {
    entitySet
       .top(1)
       .includeTotalCount()
       .execute()
       .then(function (result1) {
           // update the total count
           document.getElementById(elemId).innerText = result1.totalCount.toString() + " rows";
       }, function (error) {
           // do whatever you want to
           totalProperty = "error";
       });
}
```

Dave

Comment: Nice, I saw the `includeTotalCount` when I was going through the properties in he javascript console, it's just a shame that there doesn't appear to be some easy built in way to get the total out. This works though.